# google spreadsheets FILTER multiple columns

Tags: filter, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I created a contact register with the following structure:

```
id + lastname + name + phone + mobile + adress + birthdate + ...
```

Now, I just want to filter for contacts which are having birthday in the next 7 days and show lastname, phone and birthdate...

So I tried this: (please ignore pseudocode in the conditions)

```
=FILTER({B:D, F:G}; DAYS([Birthdate];[TODAY()])>=0; 
              DAYS([Birthdate];[TODAY()])<=7)
```

I also tried this from a post in the [Google Docs Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/-lHbCWYwVTU/vk6CBYNLAQAJ)
, but I always  get `Error, Formula parse error.`.

When I separate the column with ; I get `Error, FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 356. column count: 1. Actual row count: 178, column count: 1.`

How can I concatenate the rages?

Comment: In which column are the dates? Can you maybe share an example spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the case, I left just two columns
[image]

The formula is:

`=FILTER(A2:A,(TEXT(B2:B,"MM/DD/"&YEAR(TODAY()))*1>=today())*(TEXT(B2:B,"MM/DD/"&YEAR(TODAY()))*1<=TODAY()+7))`

---

in some regions semicolon is used: `;`

The formula for them is:

`=FILTER(A2:A;(TEXT(B2:B;"MM/DD/"&YEAR(TODAY()))*1>=today())*(TEXT(B2:B;"MM/DD/"&YEAR(TODAY()))*1<=TODAY()+7))`

Comment: Imagin there is a column C and I want to filter A and C, with the condition on B.
How can I do this? :)

Comment: `=filter({A:A, C:C}, some condition)`

Comment: Already tried this...
Get Formula parse error with , instead of ;

Comment: Replace comma with semicolon and try this: `=filter({A:A\C:C}; some condition)`